# Fields Read-only after Import from XML Workspace Document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, personal-geodatabase, arcgis-10.7, geodatabase-xml

I have a process that I follow where I import from XML into a Personal Geodatabase (PGDB), do some checks and updates, and then load into an enterprise GDB.

[image]

Now after I've imported from XML I currently have to copy/paste all the feature classes into another PGDB in order for the attribute fields to be editable.  If I try to edit them in the first PGDB, after they've been imported from XML, I just get messages along the lines of "field not editable"

When I right-click > Properties on one of the fields, the Field Properties dialog shows the field as being Read Only, and the option is disabled so I don't seem to be able to change it.

[image]

So, how can I either a) make the Import XML Workspace Document import as not read-only, or failing that b) make all my fields writable after doing the import, without having to copy all the feature classes first?

Running ArcGIS 10.7.1.  I have also tried doing the import into a File GDB with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field definition tag (for each field) in the XML Workspace Document file called `<Editable>`.  If a field is not editable after an import from the XML Workspace Document, it is probably because this tag has been set to `false`.

Change the tag value to `true` for each field that needs to be editable.

Change:

```XML
<Editable>false</Editable>
```

to:

```XML
<Editable>true</Editable>
```

A quick and easy way to do this is to open the XML Workspace Document file in a text editor like Notepad++, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog, and enter the two lines above into the Find and Replace fields, and click on the "Replace All" button.

[image]